Transfer pictures from PC to iPhone?
I'm struggling to find a working solution for what seems like a basic task: transferring old photos from my PC to my iPhone while preserving EXIF data and geotags. Despite trying various strategies suggested on platforms like Reddit, SuperUser, and ChatGPT, none have been successful. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
1. Using iTunes

Advice Given: Install iTunes on Windows, then navigate to Devices > Pictures to transfer photos.
Outcome: This doesn't work because iTunes doesn't provide a section for managing or viewing photos.

2. Using iCloud for Windows

Advice Given: Install iCloud on Windows and use it to sync photos.
Outcome: This syncs the pictures to iCloud, but not directly to the device, which is not what I need.

3. Direct USB Cable Transfer

Advice Given: Connect your iPhone via USB-C and copy pictures directly to internal storage.
Outcome: When the iPhone is connected, it appears in "This PC/Apple iPhone/Internal Storage," but the storage is read-only, preventing direct copying.

4. Using iMazing by DigiDNA

Advice Given: Install iMazing (paid software with a 50-image trial), use the Import function to transfer photos.
Outcome: This partially works; the photos sync to an album named "From My Mac," but the photos cannot be moved, renamed, or deleted on the iPhone.

I'm looking for a simple and reliable method to transfer hundred of photos from my PC to my iPhone, ensuring that EXIF data and geotags are preserved, and that the photos can be fully managed on the iPhone. Is there any solution for such simple task?

What is your PC operating system?  I have a procedure that works for me.  My system is XUbuntu 24.04.

The author mentioned Windows and every software by name exists on Windows not Linux.

I am using WIndows, Unix and Linux, not macOS.

From iCloud, you could download the photos back to your phone. Not ideal, but should at least give you a way.

The question author says

I am using WIndows, Unix and Linux

On Ubuntu, which is a version of Unix, I regularly take photos off a iPhone XS Max while preserving lots of exif data.
My system has the libimobiledevice-utils package installed.  My GUI is that associated with the XUbuntu version of Ubuntu. Sometimes it's as easy as plugging in the iPhone to a USB port.  Other times, it's more difficult but always via a USB port.  The proceedure for when it doesn't come right up is the following:
This is done at the main console of the system.  The iPhone should be unlocked at the time.
Normally
When plugged in with the lightning cord (to USB), the iPhone should show up on file manager.  If not, try a few more times.  See below if that does not work.
Click on iPhone in file manager then go down through the directory structure until your images appear.  There you move all images using Cut and Paste.
Sometimes the iPhone will ask if you want to trust the computer and may require the phone unlock password (not the apple password).
If after a few attempts the photo area still does not appear

Plug the iphone into a USB port
At a terminal command prompt issue the following:

sudo usbmuxd -f -v
If it says already running, it will provide a number (PID). Use that number in the kill command of the next step.
sudo kill -9 number (usually 4 to 6 digits)
now do the command again (sudo usbmuxd -f -v)
if a bunch of lines come through the it's OK - don't exit yet.


In a file manager, select the iPhone. If iPhone doesn't come up on a new file manager, then disconnect the iPhone USB cable.  Wait a few seconds and reconnect the iPhone cable  Look for iPhone in file manager again
Copy pictures from the iPhone as desired.
Unmount the iPhone.
Use Ctrl+C to stop the usbmuxd command still running at the terminal command prompt.
Verify the pictures have been copied

